get current page coordinates
I'm trying to log the absolute/page coordinates of some items on a page for further processing. Basically: if I'm in horizontal mode, I want a command to know where the next thing (text, PNG image, or TikZ drawing) will end up on the page, and write the results to the logfile.
So I try this, courtesy of another question on TeX stackexchange:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

This is some text.

For testing things out.

\newcommand{\logpos}[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \coordinate (x) at (0, 0);
        \path[overlay] let \p1=($(x)-(current page.south west)$)
                       in \pgfextra{\typeout{LOG #1 \x1,\y1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\logpos{separate line}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\logpos{second box}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}

aaa

\logpos{inline}aaa

\end{document}

The result is that the second box ends up shifted to the right by a bit relative to the first one, I guess because either the logpos box itself has nonzero width, or the "separator" between the box and the following tikz drawing takes up space.
Weirdly enough, the two aaa lines/paragraphs do not have a spacing issue, but if I move the closing bracket from the logpos definition to a new line on its own then I do get the second aaa indented, which doesn't seem to make any sense.
I've tried inserting a negative hspace of about the right amount at the end of the logpos command, but if I have a table of boxes and some of them have a logpos and some don't, then everything is not perfectly aligned --- zoom in and you can see a difference. Even at normal size on a screen, sometimes some boxes are visibly a couple of pixels off.
Putting an \ on the end of the logpos{second box} line does not help.
To clarify what I want:

A way to get the page coordinates of the current position in the text and print it to the logfile.
That takes up no space and doesn't influence any of the typesetting around it.
The measurement command itself doesn't need to use TikZ if there's a simpler way in plain TeX, but the things I want to measure are sometimes TikZ drawings and sometimes not.
It won't work to have the measurement command inside the TikZ object I want to measure, for reasons related to the workflow this whole thing sits inside.


The page coordinates should be stored in the aux file along with the pgfid.

This is basically what tikzmark does. It writes the coordinates of the current point to the aux file.

Short answer to your specific spacing problem, with
\logpos{second box}
\begin{tikzpicture}

you have a space (end of line) between \logpos{...} and \begin{tikzpicture}. It's not the case in
\logpos{inline}aaa

So, simply comment the end of line
\logpos{second box}%
\begin{tikzpicture}

Note that, as defined:
\newcommand{\logpos}[1]{

your command add a space. For example, aaa\logpos{inline}bbb gives

As previous, add a %
\newcommand{\logpos}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \coordinate (x) at (0, 0);
        \path[overlay] let \p1=($(x)-(current page.south west)$)
                       in \pgfextra{\typeout{LOG #1 \x1,\y1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

See also What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?).
Example:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

This is some text.

For testing things out.

\newcommand{\logpos}[1]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
        \coordinate (x) at (0, 0);
        \path[overlay] let \p1=($(x)-(current page.south west)$)
                       in \pgfextra{\typeout{LOG #1 \x1,\y1}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\logpos{separate line}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\logpos{second box}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw (0, 0) rectangle (1, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}

aaa

\logpos{inline}aaa

\end{document}


